# Is it possible to publish to Maven Central Repository from SourceForge?

Tags: java, git, maven

I wanted to publish an open source Java library to Maven, so it's easily acessible to other projects. The Git repository is at SourceForge, but I don't quite understand if it's possible to publish from here or not.

Reading the [Maven guide to uploading artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/repository/guide-central-repository-upload.html) I see that only three repositories are "approved". Namely:

- Apache Software Foundation
- FuseSource Forge
- Nuiton.org

**My Question**

If I create a secondary git repository in one of those, wouldn't that be a hassle to keep both git repositories in sync? I mean, is it wise to have duplicate git repositories, just to be able to publish to the Maven Central Repository?

What sensible options do I have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, nexus private repository is the common way to share our 3rd party jar for private use.

https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype

you can build your own repostory with the guide

Comment: Wouldn't that require to pay at least $100 a month (cheapest pricing) to host the repository? In my case this is an open source free project. Sigh.

Comment: @JoeDiNottra both nexus and cloud server have free version you do not need to pay

Answer (score 5):

From the link you attached:

> Automatic publication will be provided for Forges that provide hosting
>   services for OSS projects and other large project repositories that
>   meet certain minimum criteria such as validation of PGP keys and pom
>   contents as defined above. If you are interested in becoming an
>   approved Forge, contact us at repo-maintainers@maven.apache.org.

Did you try this method?
Another option, again from the link:

> The easiest way to upload another project is to use the Open Source
>   [Software Repository Hosting (OSSRH)](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html), which is an approved repository
>   provided by Sonatype for any OSS Project that want to get their
>   artifacts into Central Repository.

However I think this one requires paying for nexus hosting

Another option is to publish to other public maven repository, see a list [here](https://www.deps.co/guides/public-maven-repositories/)

Comment: Manually uploading to OSSRH when releasing is a simple way to do it and doesn't require any specific hosting or version control system.  It is free/gratis for open source projects.